# UTF-8 and colour printing woes…

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have a console program that outputs in wonderful colour. For errors, the following code is used with some trivial examples at the bottom.

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from sys import stderr
from colored import fg
from colored import attr
from locale import getpreferredencoding

def format_error(x):
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(fg(88), x, attr('reset'))

def print_error(x):
    msg = format_error('✗  {0}\n'.format(x))
    stderr.write(msg.encode(getpreferredencoding()))

print_error(str('ook'))
print_error(unicode(b'café', 'UTF-8'))
```

I have no control over that `x` is.  It could be anything. Also, some of this script is called from a GUI that captures `stdout`/`stderr` via [glib-spawn-async](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--spawn-async). As such, from time to time, I get `UnicodeDecodeError` errors. I have read the [Unicode HOWTo](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) but clearly I am missing something.

*How can I harden my code such that `UnicodeDecodeError` are never raised?*

For example, within a `gtk.textview`, I get the following whereas on the console, all is fine. Trace has been cut to remove irrelevant data.

```
 File "/home/usr/nifty_logger.py", line 96, in print_success
    sys.stdout.write(msg.encode(getpreferredencoding()))
  File "/home/usr/.virtualenvs/rprs_bootstrap/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: So what is the *full traceback* of the error? And what exactly are you trying to encode when it is raised (try to record the `repr(x)` output).

Comment: Also, `colored` returns byte strings, not Unicode text, so you are mixing bytes and Unicode here. You may want to decode those first (they are all ASCII bytes, lucky for you).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Something like `'{0}{1}{2}'.format(fg(88).decode('utf-8'), text, attr('reset').decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: `.decode('ascii')` should do. Python 2 does this implicitly for you, which is why this hasn't really been an issue, but you may want to consider using byte strings here (so encode `text` first, then add the color codes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well the new code works fine on the console and fails within the `gtk.TextView` with the same error.

Comment: I didn't say that that was the solution, and is why I left that as a *comment*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In any case, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [encode()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) takes an optional argument defining the error handling:

```
str.encode([encoding[, errors]])
```

From the docs:

> Return an encoded version of the string. Default encoding is the current default string encoding. errors may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The default for errors is 'strict', meaning that encoding errors raise a UnicodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace' and any other name registered via codecs.register_error(), see section Codec Base Classes. For a list of possible encodings, see section Standard Encodings.

In your case:

```
msg.encode(getpreferredencoding(), 'backslashreplace')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I answered before the traceback was added. This does not change the essence of the answer.